# Setting element attributes without jquery

Tags: javascript

I am able to set attributes using jquery like the example below

```
$('#MyElement').attr('max', 5);
```

How can i accomplish this without using jquery?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute

Comment: [You Might Not Need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) is an awesome reference for these.

Comment: Thanks for the references!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").setAttribute("max", 5);
```

Some reference for [setAttribute()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute) in regular JavaScript:

```
var element = document.getElementById('MyElement');
element.setAttribute('max', 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native JavaScript [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute) function.

```
var element = document.getElementById("MyElement")
element.setAttribute("max", 5);
```